# what difference of managed and unmanaged hconnection in hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing

When i  tried to create a HTable instance in this way.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HConnection conn = HConnectionManager.getConnection(conf);
conn.getTable("TABLE_NAME");
```

Then i got a Exception.

```
    @Override
    public HTableInterface getTable(TableName tableName, ExecutorService pool) throws IOException {
      if (managed) {
        throw new IOException("The connection has to be unmanaged.");
      }
      return new HTable(tableName, this, pool);
    }
```

So , i wants to know the concrete reflection of managed and 'unmanaged'  Hconnection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before call `HConnectionManager.getConnection` you have to create connection using `HConnectionManager.createConnection` passing to it earlier created `HBaseConfiguration` instance. `HConnectionManager.getConnection` return connection which is already exists. A bit of `HConnectionManager` javadoc about how it handle connection pool:

> This class has a static Map of HConnection instances keyed by Configuration; all invocations of getConnection(Configuration) that pass the sameConfiguration instance will be returned the sameHConnection instance

In your case, you can simply create connection using `HConnectionManager.createConnection` and  use returned connection to open `HTable`

Edit:

@ifiddddddbest, I found javadocs for `HConnectionImplementation` which has description of managed flag(may be it will help you to understand):

> @param managed If true, does not do full shutdown on close; i.e.
>   cleanup of connection to zk and shutdown of all services; we just
>   close down the resources this connection was responsible for and
>   decrement usage counters.  It is up to the caller to do the full
>   cleanup.  It is set when we want have connection sharing going on --
>   reuse of zk connection, and cached region locations, established
>   regionserver connections, etc.  When connections are shared, we have
>   reference counting going on and will only do full cleanup when no more
>   users of an HConnectionImplementation instance.

In the newer versions of HBase(>1.0), managed flag was disappeared and all connection management now on client side,e.g. client responsible to close it and if it do this, it close all internal connections to ZK,to HBase master, etc, not only decrease reference counter.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Lagrang.                                                              
yes, The method is correct. but  when i  saw  **ConnectionManager's**  source code . 
i found **getConnection((final Configuration conf))**   method  will  call  **createConnection(final Configuration conf, final boolean managed)**  .but its "managed"  parameter is 'true'.    this is what i wants to know ? why  use ' ture ' .  what does  "managed"   stand for?